# Change non-consecutive indices to consecutive

Tags: r

I have data like this:

```
   doc_id sentence_id token_id head_token_id
1    doc1           1        1             0
2    doc1           1        2             1
3    doc1           1        3             1
4    doc1           1        4             3
5    doc1           1        5             4
6    doc1           1        6             1
7    doc1           2        1             2
8    doc1           2        2             0
9    doc1           2        3             2
10   doc1           2        4             3
11   doc1           2        5             2
12   doc2           1        1             0
13   doc2           1        2             1
14   doc2           1        3             4
15   doc2           1        4             1
```

The data is grouped by columns "doc_id" and "sentence_id". The "head_token_id" column is an order column. However, the order values are *not* consecutive. For example, the values of "head_token_id" for `doc_id == "doc_1"` and `sentence_id == 1` are `0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1`. I want to change them to consecutive values `0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1`. I want to do this within each group of "doc_id" and "sentence_id".

My desired output is like this with new_head_token_id column.
Numbers 0 and 1 from head_token_id always be the same. But rest of numbers might be the same or not. In depends if earlier number exists in this sentence or not. For example

```
   doc_id sentence_id token_id head_token_id new_head_token_id
4    doc1           1        4             3                 2
```

here we see that 3 from head_token_id changed to 2, because in this sentence(sentence 1, doc 1) in column head_token_id there is no number 2. I try to deleted 'jumps of numbers'.

```
   doc_id sentence_id token_id head_token_id new_head_token_id
1    doc1           1        1             0                 0
2    doc1           1        2             1                 1
3    doc1           1        3             1                 1
4    doc1           1        4             3                 2
5    doc1           1        5             4                 3
6    doc1           1        6             1                 1
7    doc1           2        1             2                 1
8    doc1           2        2             0                 0
9    doc1           2        3             2                 1
10   doc1           2        4             3                 2
11   doc1           2        5             2                 1
12   doc2           1        1             0                 0
13   doc2           1        2             1                 1
14   doc2           1        3             4                 2
15   doc2           1        4             1                 1
```

I think the first part of code should be like this

```
for (i in unique(df$doc_id)){
  for(j in unique(df$sentence_id){
    for(k in df$token_id){
      if(df$head_token_id[k] == 0){df$new_head_token_id[k] = 0} else
        if(df$head_token_id[k] == 1){df$new_head_token_id[k] = 1}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the algorithm for this? If you just want to change the order, pass DF a vector of row numbers to reflect this.

Comment: I've tried to figure out the algorithm for this, because in real I have very big data set with 100 000 documents

Comment: What I don't understand is, the seventh number in `head_token_id` is a 2 though?

Comment: yes the seventh number in head_token_id is a 2.
seventh number is first word in second sentence in doc1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answer for this. In one doc and one sentence we have to find how many unique values is lower than current checking value and replace current value on this number. 
For example, the values of `"head_token_id" for doc_id == "doc_1" and sentence_id == 1 are 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1.` For value 3 only TWO unique values are lower ( 0 and 1). So we want to change 3 to 2.

Code below:

```
levels<-function(parsedDataFrame)
{parsedDataFrame$head_token_id=as.numeric(parsedDataFrame$head_token_id)
for(doc in unique(parsedDataFrame[,1]))
    {for(prg in unique(parsedDataFrame[,2]))
        {for(stc in unique(parsedDataFrame[,3]))
            {
                newDataFrame=parsedDataFrame[which(parsedDataFrame[,1]==doc & parsedDataFrame[,2]==prg & parsedDataFrame[,3]==stc),]
                newDataFrame$sentenceLevel=sapply(newDataFrame$head_token_id,function(y) length(which(y>unique(newDataFrame$head_token_id))))

                if(exists("levelsDF"))
                  levelsDF=rbind(levelsDF,newDataFrame)
                else levelsDF=newDataFrame
            }
        }   
    }
    return(levelsDF)    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This relabeling is pretty easy to do treating the variable as a factor. We can then coerce it back to numeric. We use the fact that `unique()` will provide the vector of unique values *in the order they occur*.

The operation we want to do on a vector `x` is

```
as.numeric(as.character(
  factor(x, levels = unique(x), labels = seq_along(unique(x)) - 1)
))
```

This will relabel the unique values of `x` with the order in which they occur. The `-1` makes it start from 0, not 1. And we coerce back to numeric. We'll make this into a function:

```
label0 = function(x) {
    as.numeric(as.character(
      factor(x, levels = unique(x), labels = seq_along(unique(x)) - 1)
    ))
}
```

Lastly, pick your favorite method of applying a function by a grouping variable. I'll use `dplyr`, but you can use `data.table`, `base::ave`, `base::by`, `split; lapply; rbind`, etc. Example of these methods and more can be found at the R-FAQ [Sum a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/903061), you just want to use `label0` instead of `sum`.

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(dat, doc_id, sentence_id) %>% mutate(new_head_token_id = label0(head_token_id))
# # A tibble: 15 x 5
# # Groups:   doc_id, sentence_id [3]
#    doc_id sentence_id token_id head_token_id new_head_token_id
#    <fctr>       <int>    <int>         <int>             <dbl>
#  1   doc1           1        1             0                 0
#  2   doc1           1        2             1                 1
#  3   doc1           1        3             1                 1
#  4   doc1           1        4             3                 2
#  5   doc1           1        5             4                 3
#  6   doc1           1        6             1                 1
#  7   doc1           2        1             2                 0
#  8   doc1           2        2             0                 1
#  9   doc1           2        3             2                 0
# 10   doc1           2        4             3                 2
# 11   doc1           2        5             2                 0
# 12   doc2           1        1             0                 0
# 13   doc2           1        2             1                 1
# 14   doc2           1        3             4                 2
# 15   doc2           1        4             1                 1
```

---

Using this data:

```
dat = read.table(text = "   doc_id sentence_id token_id head_token_id
1    doc1           1        1             0
2    doc1           1        2             1
3    doc1           1        3             1
4    doc1           1        4             3
5    doc1           1        5             4
6    doc1           1        6             1
7    doc1           2        1             2
8    doc1           2        2             0
9    doc1           2        3             2
10   doc1           2        4             3
11   doc1           2        5             2
12   doc2           1        1             0
13   doc2           1        2             1
14   doc2           1        3             4
15   doc2           1        4             1", head = T)
```

Comment: doc1,sentence2 and doc2,sentence1 are wrong in new_head_token_id column

Comment: When I used your code on my computer only doc1,sentence2 is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you need grouping by sentence as well. Just add that to the group by: `group_by(dat, doc_id, sentence_id)`, the rest is the same. Answer edited.

Comment: still it doesn't work. Look at doc1 sentence2..
0 and 1 should stay the same always